# What laser power for cutting and engraving wood and Acrylic robot baseplates?

Tags: laser

Need to buy a DIY/High School grade laser cutter/engraver

**How much laser power** is needed for **wood, acrylic (3 to 6mm thick), cutting and decorative engraving?**

What parameters I need to take care in selecting suitable machines?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I edited to clarify 3 to 6mm thickness for acrylic robot base plate cutting

Answer (score 1):

For such results the laser should have a power of 2-3Watts

You can have a look at different projects like this here at kickstarter:
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1537608281/lazerblade-the-affordable-laser-cutter-engraver